# How to read pdf file content and display into html

Tags: php, pdf

I want to display `.pdf` file content in my php website in form of html.

How to read pdf file content and display as same format as it is in pdf?

Comment: Is it what you're looking for? https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recommended way to embed PDF in HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/291813/recommended-way-to-embed-pdf-in-html)